# NullPointerException on Dialog box - Android

Tags: java, android, dialog, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement a `dialog` box to appear when a button is clicked.  I followed an example to get this below code since I have never worked with `dialogs` before.  I am getting a NPE in 2 separate spots in my `Results` class.  I have commented in my code below both spots.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Java code:

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    Button detailsBtn;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultsmain);

        detailsBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.detailsBtn);
        detailsBtn.setText("Details");

        detailsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.resultsdetailsdisplay);
                dialog.setTitle("Detailssss");

                TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText("TITLE - TESTING");  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

                Button close = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);

                close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

resultsdetailsdisplay.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat output

```
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.Results$4.onClick(Results.java:85)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-13 18:36:39.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Include the exception stack for better answers.

Comment: Oh yea, forgot.  I edited it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the dialog object:

```
TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

and

```
Button close = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
```

As specified [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29):
**findViewById** - Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

Your dialog is loading after the fact so only the dialog context knows about these views.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I don't really understand what you instructed me to do.

Comment: notice the 'dialog.' object reference, instead of using an unqualified call to findViewById i'm using the dialog object as it 'knows' about your two view objects.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just could not see it before!  :)  I implemented your code and both NPE's are gone.  Thanks!  Nothing happens when the button is pushed now but that apparently is a different issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`TextView tv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);`

`Button close = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);`

Here in the above xml you're not creating the `button` also.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: resultsdetailsdisplay.xml doesn't contain any button element and in the code trying to access R.id.close for the dialog. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are caused by the same method, `findViewById(R.id.something)`. Since you try to reference your views from an outside class (namely `OnClickListener`) you cannot use `findViewById` directly. Instead you may use for example,

```
Results.this.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Same NPE's appear on the same lines.